# How to recognize left/right swipe gestures? More lenient than UISwipeGestureRecognizer.direction.right/left

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement swipe to dismiss views in my app. I'm using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, and on a left or right swipe the view gets dismissed. However, UISwipeGestureRecognizer has an incredibly strict definition of left or right - unless the swipe is perfectly horizontal, it doesn't get recognized. It's cumbersome to use since most users physically cannot swipe that perfectly each time. Is there a more forgiving way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
                    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

                    var initialPoint: CGPoint = .zero

                    switch pan.state {
                    case .began:
                        initialPoint = pan.translation(in: self)
                        break

                    case .changed:
                        let panned = pan.translation(in: self)
                        if panned.x > initialPoint.x {
                            // right
                        } else if panned.x < initialPoint.x {
                            // left
                        }
                        break

                    default:
                        break
                    }
```